# Which wire should I use as dummy load for this specific PSU

Tags: power-supply, resistors, dummy-load

I'd like to make lab power supply out of my old ATX Power supply. I am beginner in electrical engineering and this project seems pretty straightforward. I've checked many tutorials about it and creators of these instructed, that there should be resistor connected to 5V or 12V wire depending on max output current that they can provide.
[image: psu sticker]

Here comes my questions:
Should I put dummy load on 5V or 12V?
Is 24ohm 5W resistor fine for connection?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just load all the lines a little bit. You're a beginning EE so try this...calculate the power dissipated by your 24ohm, 5W resistor when connected across the 5V line and when connected across the 12V line. Does your result tell you it's okay?

Comment: You will likely need a jumper from "power on" lead to ground to get the supply to turn on. A 1W load may be below the minimum for a 450W supply to be in regulation.

Answer (score 0):

A 24Ohm/5W is okay for the 5V rail, but not sufficient for the 12V rail.
12V / 24Ohms = 0,5A * 12V = 6W
Your resistor will probably get very hot, possibly fail, and possibly result in smoke or flames.

Comment: For better step Load ripple response a 5% preload is suggested from my experience. Also newer PSU’s <10y old, >=450W,  run fine with no load. Older ones 250W,300W PSU’s needed a preload just to be stable on primary power output only. all others are forward coupled by transformer and share primary switched  current of SMPS. Ie. not individually regulated.  Some HIGH power PSU’s have independent 12V outputs shown in datasheet might suggest preload, but it won’t hurt with(without) it.

Comment: It looks like your answer is missing some words.